# Unificar dos consultas en SQL Server

Tags: sql

Estoy buscando la manera de unificar dos consultas en sql para obtener la suma de una columna con un criterio, menos la suma de la misma columna pero con otro criterio de busqueda. No estoy seguro de si es posible ya que estuve investigando pero no he logrado encontrar un ejemplo similar.

```
consulta2 = "SELECT SUM(Transferido) AS 'QtyRecibido' 
FROM Produccion.Transferido WHERE WO = '"+jTextIngresoWO.getText()+"' 
AND AreaRecibe = '"+LineaActual()+"' AND Estado = 'Completo'";

consulta3 = "SELECT SUM(Transferido) AS 'QtyEnviado' 
FROM Produccion.Transferido WHERE WO = '"+jTextIngresoWO.getText()+"' 
AND AreaEntrega = '"+LineaActual()+"'";
```

Ambas son la sumatoria de material transferido de un departamento hacia otro en donde "Consulta2" refleja lo que he recibido de otro departamento, y 
"Consulta3" lo que he enviado hacia otro departamento.
Las dos consultas las estoy realizando desde java, pero necesito unificarlas en una sola si fuera posible.

Comment: Entoncesel problema no es java, es de sql y tendrias que poner eso en las etiquetas. Y aclara la base de datos, porque es importante para saber como resolverla

Comment: Amigo, yo lo agregué en las etiquetas pero alguien sugierió una correccion en el post y eliminó esa etiqueta, ademas de que si la consulta no corre en SQL tampoco corre en java, ya sea por sintaxis o estructura, por eso la formulé enfocado en SQL, gracias por el comentario, lo aprecio mucho!!

Comment: tu problema no es java, porque no hay codigo java. Por eso quite la etiqueta. Esta pregunta es la misma si estuvieras programando en php o en C#. el problema no es java, es pura y exclusivamente de sql.

Comment: Honestamente creí que era importante mencionarlo ya que en realidad la consulta la realizo desde JAVA pero estaba asegurandome que la sintaxis estuviera correcta y que la logica funcional no causara problemas en sql server.

Comment: Esta bien. pero en este caso, vos queres unir dos querys, asi que no importa de donde vienen. El lenguaje en el que programes no influye sobre tu base de datos. Pero si es importante saber a que base de datos te referis.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lamentablemente no puedo probar que esta consulta funciona, sobretodo por el caso de la selección de múltiples tablas con FROM en SQL Server (del cual no tengo mucho conocimiento), pero quiero dar a entender que la idea general es la de crear dos subconsultas y seleccionar la suma de cada una de ellas. Luego de esto puedes hacer operaciones entre estos resultados en el primer `SELECT`.

```
SELECT
    re.QtyRecibido,
    en.QtyEnviado
FROM (
    SELECT
        COALESCE(
            SUM(Transferido),
            0 ) AS 'QtyRecibido'
    FROM
        Produccion.Transferido
    WHERE 
        WO = '"+jTextIngresoWO.getText()+"' 
        AND AreaRecibe = '"+LineaActual()+"' 
        AND Estado = 'Completo'
) re ,(
    SELECT
        COALESCE(
            SUM(Transferido),
            0 ) AS 'QtyEnviado'
    FROM 
        Produccion.Transferido
    WHERE 
        WO = '"+jTextIngresoWO.getText()+"' 
        AND AreaEntrega = '"+LineaActual()+"'
) en
```

Comment: Mil gracias, esta última sugerencia me ayudó mucho para resolver el problema, Pura Vida gente!!

Comment: Perfecto, recuerda puntuar positiva o negativamente las respuestas según el aporte que hicieron. Además, si fuese el caso, de elegir la respuesta que más te ayudó a resolver tu problema.

Comment: Amigo, una consulta referente a este mismo tema, como te dije cuando ejecuto la consulta en SQL esa forma que me sugeriste funciona perfectamente, pero por alguna razon cuando ejecuto la misma consulta en java no me trae ningun valor, tecnicamente la sintaxis es la misma que ud utilizó en el ejemplo, pero cuando la ejecuto para guardar los valores en un array no me trae ninguno de los valores que si se ven reflejados en SQL server, será acaso por el formato de la consulta? ya que en todos los demas procedimientos que hago guardo valores en arrays y solo en este tengo ese problema

Comment: Te sugiero varias cosas, que ese problema lo plantees en otro post, y justamente ahí ya involucres la etiqueta de java. Además de, al menos como yo lo hago en python, depurar esa consulta con todos los datos ya llenos, es decir. Ten la consulta pero, antes de ejecutarla, muestra en la consola o registros la consulta final, con todos los datos ya llenados y revisa si hay algún error.

Comment: Perfecto, lo haré.... Pura Vida!!

Answer (score 0):

Se me ocurre que puedes hacer algo como esto:
- separaR las columbas QtyRecibido y QtyEnviado

Un ejemplo a continuación.

```
SELECT 
    SUM(Transferido) AS 'QtyRecibido',
    '' AS 'QtyEnviado' 
FROM Produccion.Transferido 
WHERE 
    WO = '"+jTextIngresoWO.getText()+"' 
    AND AreaRecibe = '"+LineaActual()+"'
    AND Estado = 'Completo';
UNION ALL
SELECT '' as 'QtyRecibido',
    SUM(Transferido) AS 'QtyEnviado' 
FROM Produccion.Transferido 
WHERE 
    WO = '"+jTextIngresoWO.getText()+"' 
    AND AreaEntrega = '"+LineaActual()+"';
```

Comment: y donde hace la cuenta este query?

Comment: Puedes agregar un campo en común por el que puedas agrupar. Posteriormente haces un select resultante con la operación que necesitas. Si puedes compartir un archivo de excel con un ejemplo mas claro del resultado que requieras, te podemos ayudar con mas facilidad.

Comment: El query genera don columnas temporales que conservan los valores obtenido, creo que tendría que hacer otra consulta adicional para poder tomar esos valores y guardarlos en un arreglo en java, corrigeme si estoy equivocado.

Comment: @Alvaro en realidad es mucho mas simple.. o lo sumas directamente en tu programa (ya que tenes los dos querys), o aclaras de que db hablas y se puede resolver facilmente

Comment: Ya lo probé y si me devuelve valores, el unico detalle que observo de momento es que debo validar cuando algun valor devuelve null, pero creo que puede funcionar, gracias por el ejemplo!!

Answer (score 0):

unión no es la respuesta, segundo lo que indicas, quieres que el resultado de ambas consultas se vean en una sola y luego poder manipular esos resultados,como tip, no hay necesidad de que el resultado de una consulta provenga de un FROM (TABLA), tu problema puede arreglarse con un FROM (SUB-CONSULTA), por ejemplo puedes hacer lo siguiente:

```
SELECT SUMA1, SUMA2
FROM ((SELECT VARIABLE FROM TABLA WHERE (RELACIÓN CON TABLA PRINCIPAL) AND...) AS SUMA1,
      (SELECT VARIABLE FROM TABLA WHERE (RELACIÓN CON TABLA PRINCIPAL)AND...) AS SUMA2
      FROM TABLA PRINCIPAL);
```

Saludos

Comment: ese query no esta bien formado.. es la idea de lo que hay que hacer.. pero ese query no esta bien... suma1 es el nombre de una tabla, no de un campo...

Comment: no entiendo cuando dices que suma1 es un nombre de tabla y no de un campo.